# How to approach the function problem?

Tags: functions

Can anybody please I am a little new to stack exchange and possibly I am confused with a homework question or rather a maths question.
In the problem I can't assume how to approach the problem because the series is becoming somewhat like 2^(2^2)^(2^2)...(n-1) times and I am a little confused how to write the general term can anyone tell me how to approach the problem.[image]

Comment: What goes wrong if you just try to compute the first few iterations?  What, for instance is $f(425628)$?  What is $f^{2}(425628)$?

Comment: Actually I am confused on how to do that I am getting a relation but cannot express it in form of and equation I guess.

Comment: What do you mean?  $f(x)$ has a perfectly straight forward definition.  What is $f(1)$?  What is $f(2)$?

Comment: Ok I am trying that never thought from that perspective.

Comment: Yes I got it.no it's not I understood what you meant yes it done thank you for your time.

Comment: What answer did you get?

Comment: I got an answer of 6.

Comment: I agree, the answer is $6$.

Comment: @MattiP. please don't edit the title to add "solved" to it. Rather, you can encourage the OP to post an answer to the question themselves, or you can post your own answer to the question to take it off the unanswered list (the chatroom [Crusade of Answers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9141/the-crusade-of-answers) might interest you if you take the latter option).